# Best file mutex in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mutex

I want to use some mutex on files, so any process won't touch certain files before other stop using them. How can I do it in .NET 3.5? Here are some details:

I have some service, which checks every period of time if there are any files/directories in certain folder and if there are, service's doing something with it.

My other process is responsible for moving files (and directories) into certain folder and everything works just fine.

But I'm worrying because there can be situation, when my copying process will copy the files to certain folder and in the same time (in the same milisecond) my service will check if there are some files, and will do something with them (but not with all of them, because it checked during the copying).

So my idea is to put some mutex in there (maybe one extra file can be used as a mutex?), so service won't check anything until copying is done.

How can I achieve something like that in possibly easy way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The "any process" clause cannot work, a program has to be written to check a mutex.  Just as any program has to be written to deal with failure when they try to open a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to achieve this is the filename:

- Process A copies the files to e.g. "somefile.ext.noprocess" (this is non-atomic)
- Process B ignores all files with the ".noprocess" suffix
- After Process B has finished copying, it renames the file to "somefile.ext"
- Next time Process B checks, it sees the file and starts processing.

If you have more than one file, that have to be processd together (or none), you need to adapt this scheme to an additional transaction file containing the file names for the transaction: Only if this file exists and has the correct name, must process B read it and process the files mentioned in it.

Comment: After Process B has finished copying, it renames the file to "somefile.ext" is it non-atomic operation too? So there can be the same problem but not during copying but during renaming?

Comment: Renaming is an atomic operation **between two processes** - if the second process already sees the new name, it can open the file without fear of interaction with the other process.

Comment: But my problem is that I have to wait until all copying is done. So I need to be sure that Service will start doing something with files only when my other process finished copying.
Maybe I can achieve this by copying extra files at the end, and service will check if this file exists, and if it does not wait for the rest of files to copy?

Comment: This is what I wrote in the second part: You have a file **set**, so you start copying the set. The other process ignores them. When you are finished copying, you write another (index-) file and (atomically) rename it to a predetermined filename pattern. The other process sees the index file and only then starts processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem really is not of mutual exclusion, but of atomicity. Copying multiple files is not an atomic operation, and so it is possible to observe the files in a half-copied state which you'd like to prevent.

To solve your problem, you could hinge your entire operation on a single atomic file system operation, for example renaming (or moving) of a folder. That way no one can observe an intermediate state. You can do it as follows:

1. Copy the files to a folder outside the monitored folder, but on the same drive.
2. When the copying operation is complete, move the folder inside the monitored folder. To any outside process, all the files would appear at once, and it would have no chance to see only part of the files.

Comment: I'm all the time on the same drive, but copying folder is not atomic (as far as I know). I'm doing it in C#, so I'm using recursion to copy whole directory and all subdirectories, files etc.

Comment: Copying a folder is not atomic, moving a folder *is* atomic.